# CakePHP 3 Assocations delete

Tags: php, cakephp

Im new to CakePHP and all this stuff with associations. When i want to delete a category i also want to delete the competences who are linked to the category. This are my table models:

**CategoriesTable.php**

```
class CategoriesTable extends Table
{
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        parent::initialize($config);

        $this->belongsToMany('Competences');
    }
}
```

**CompetencesTable.php**

```
class CompetencesTable extends Table
{
     public function initialize(array $config)
     {
        parent::initialize($config);

        $this->belongsToMany('Categories');
        $this->belongsToMany('CategoriesCompetences');
     }
}
```

**CategoriesCompetencesTable.php**

```
class CategoriesCompetencesTable extends Table
{
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        parent::initialize($config);

        $this->belongsTo('Categories');
        $this->hasMany('Competences');
    }
}
```

When i delete a category it deletes the rows in the link table, but not in the competences in CompetenceTable.. I know that i forget something, but cant figure out what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you have a hasMany assoc in your join table to Competences. Is there a reason? It should be belongsTo. If no try setting in the associations options `dependent => true` of the hasMany assoc.

[See the documentation for hasMany()](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/associations.html#hasmany-associations). It's a good idea to read the whole page carefully.

```
public function initialize(array $config)
{
    $this->hasMany('Competences', [
        'foreignKey' => 'article_id',
        'dependent' => true,
    ]);
}
```